# Parse Error in PHP and Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

> E/InputlineResult: 
> **Warning**:  mysql_connect(): Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'DESKTOP-2Q0OODR' (using password: NO) in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\chatter\mysql.class.php** on line **28**
>       03-29 22:33:50.633 7032-17538/com.baidar.androidChatter E/InputlineResult: 
> **Warning**:  mysql_connect(): Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'DESKTOP-2Q0OODR' (using password: NO) in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\chatter\mysql.class.php** on line **28**
>       03-29 22:33:50.633 7032-17538/com.baidar.androidChatter E/OuterResult: 
> **Warning**:  mysql_connect(): Access denied
>   for user 'root'@'DESKTOP-2Q0OODR' (using password: NO) in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\chatter\mysql.class.php** on line **28**
> **Warning**:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be
>   resource, boolean given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\chatter\mysql.class.php** on line **68**

```
<?php



class MySQL
{   
    private $dbLink;
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbUsername;
    private $dbPassword;
    private $dbName;
    public  $queryCount;

    function MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName)
    {
        $this->dbHost = $dbHost;
        $this->dbUsername = $dbUsername;
        $this->dbPassword = $dbPassword;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;    
        $this->queryCount = 0;      
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }
    //connect to database
    private function connect() {    
        $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);     
        if (!$this->dbLink) {           
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("set names latin5",$this->dbLink);
            return true;
        }
        unset ($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);     
    }   
    /*****************************
     * Method to close connection *
     *****************************/
    function close()
    {
        @mysql_close($this->dbLink);
    }
    /*******************************************
     * Checks for MySQL Errors
     * If error exists show it and return false
     * else return true  
     *******************************************/
    function ShowError()
    {
        $error = mysql_error();
        //echo $error;      
    }   
    /****************************
     * Method to run SQL queries
     ****************************/
    function  query($sql)
    {   
        if (!$this->dbLink) 
            $this->connect();

        if (! $result = mysql_query($sql,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();         
            return false;
        }
        $this->queryCount++;    
        return $result;
    }
    /************************
    * Method to fetch values*
    *************************/
    function fetchObject($result)
    {
        if (!$Object=mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $Object;
        }
    }
    /*************************
    * Method to number of rows
    **************************/
    function numRows($result)
    {
        if (false === ($num = mysql_num_rows($result))) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return -1;
        }
        return $num;        
    }
    /*******************************
     * Method to safely escape strings
     *********************************/
    function escapeString($string)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            return $string;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $string = mysql_escape_string($string);
            return $string;
        }
    }

    function free($result)
    {
        if (mysql_free_result($result)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }

    function lastInsertId()
    {
        return mysql_insert_id($this->dbLink);
    }

    function getUniqueField($sql)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($this->query($sql));

        return $row[0];
    }
    function testconnection() { 
        $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);     
        if (!$this->dbLink) {           
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->dbLink)) {
            $this->ShowError();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("set names latin5",$this->dbLink);
            return true;
        }
        unset ($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);     
    }       
}
```

In the 28th line the code says `Fatal Error`, on line 68th it says `access denied`.

> line 28-> $this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
>   line 68-> if (! $result = mysql_query($sql,$this->dbLink))

Comment: Is this a real host "DESKTOP-2Q0OODR"? May be it must be a localhost? Can you connect to your DB using console client with those connection settings?

Answer (score 1):

The error message pretty much says it all. You, with the credentials you try do not have the right to access the database. A big clue is that the error message is telling you that you try to access the database without a password.

The mistake is that you have written a function called `MySQL` into the `class` called `MySQL` which was probably intended to be a constructor, since this is how you write constructors in so many languages, like Java & co. Change it to

```
function __construct($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName)
```

Also, [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is considered to be unsafe and deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/ro/book.mysqli.php) instead and beware [SQL injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) as well.